# How and where to set the property "AWT.DnD.flavorMapFileURL" for custom mime types

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, awt, mime-types

When a JVM starts it prepares a map of native mime type vs. java data flavors.
This mapping is present in `jdk/jre/lib/flavormap.properties`.

According to the comments in the file, one can augment the mapping by specifying the `AWT.DnD.flavorMapFileURL` property in the appropriate `awt.properties` file.

I struggled a bit to get it work but no much success.
I want to know that where can I locate this `awt.properties` and what is the format to set the property `AWT.DnD.flavorMapFileURL`.

Comment: *"one can augment the mapping"* What is the point of doing so? It won't be practical to do that for your end users. See [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: The requirement  is that I want add custom mime type so that the I can use my own data flavour.

Comment: *"I want add custom mime type"* A Java desktop application can be launched using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). JWS can declare a mime-type for files of that type, using the JNLP API. It is achieved using [`IntegrationService.requestAssociation(String mimetype, String[] extensions)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/IntegrationService.html#requestAssociation-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-)